# Meaning and application of convolution or deconvolution in physical sciences

Tags: mathematics

In which real case scenarios a convolution or deconvolution operation is useful ?

Comment: I think this question is too broad to be answered correctly. We will just have an endless list ... Why are you asking ?

Comment: Anytime there are waves, but I don't think this the answer you are looking for... :-)

Comment: It's useful if it casts your problem in a form that you can solve easily?

Comment: @Cedric I'm trying to find a real case, simple scenario where a convolution is used. I don't think we are going to have an endless list. I am looking for a very specific answer, the one that explains clearly how a convolution/deconvolution is practically used in real-world science.

Comment: @Stefano: I advise you to look at the [similar question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/5892/what-is-convolution-intuitively) asked at mathoverflow. It's obviously more mathematical than physical but you might gain a nice intuition there.

Comment: Convolution appears when you model a linear system... It is like a question about the application of diff calculus...

Comment: A practical application: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocoder ;-) Not science, but it's widely used in sci-fi!

Comment: @Cedric: why is big list a problem? I think that it's a great thing to have lots of answers and let the community pick the best ones. In fact, questions asking for big lists are among the best there are (e.g. at mathoverflow). You just have to tag them big-list and make them community wiki and let the magic happen. Of course, strong community is required for this to work.

Comment: @Marek, agreed, there are *classic* questions on the original SO with hundreds of answers. Probably these kinds of questions should be community owned though.

Comment: @Sklivvz: CW is outdated and likely to be removed soon from SE sites as well. See Stackoverflow meta. I also prompt reading "bad subjective/good subjective" on joel's blog. I apologize not to provide links, but I raised this many times in other SEs and I am bored of repeating myself... sorry. this is my fault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any real instrument will have some [impulse response](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_response).  The measured signal is the convolution of the source signal with this impulse response.  For example, if you aim a telescope at a point source, you will see not a point source but the point source convolved with the [point spread function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_spread_function) (2D impulse response) of the telescope.  Some kind of (usually approximate) [deconvolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deconvolution) is applied to correct this and better estimate the source signal.

Answer (score 2):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Applications

Comment: the point of googling stuff has been discussed at length on all the meta sites since the very inception of SE, and the conclusion forms the very philosophy behind SE sites. We want to localize knowledge, not point to links that can become outdated. The goal is to have this answer as the first google entry (see: "google as an interface" SE concept) so that people can learn immediately a well-written answer to a very specific question. I encourage you to browse the meta sites (not only the physics meta, but stackoverflow meta as well), to see the rationale behind my point.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very general topic to discuss, (I'm not sure there's a right answer here), but I think it's very much worth pointing out the convolution theorem. It's not a "practical" application per se, but it's a very useful method, since Fourier analysis enters physics in so many areas. Anywhere where you encounter *spectrum analysis*, convolutions will quite possibly come into play somewhere.

The [convolution theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem) states:

$$\mathcal{F}\{f*g\} = \mathcal{F}\{f\} \cdot \mathcal{F}\{g\}$$

$$\mathcal{F}\{f \cdot g\}= \mathcal{F}\{f\}*\mathcal{F}\{g\}$$

where $\mathcal{F}$ represents the Fourier transform operator.

These are remarkably useful identities when performing Fourier transforms. Since Fourier transforms can in fact be used for solving some differential equations, they have a notable application there too.

Answer (score 0):

Solving the Fresnel diffraction integral, to find the amplitude and phase of waves near a source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_diffraction#Convolution

Answer (score 0):

Convolution is applied whenever the amount of a quantity is simultaneously being produced and undergoing another change and then these effects added up over time.

A practical example I've heard is when you produce radioactive material at a certain rate $f(t)$ (which decays from the moment it appears). At any moment $t$, we have total amount equal to  $(f\star g)(t)$, where $g(t) = e^{-kt}$.